# issues with modal on click javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

for some reason, one a pass the following URL  only one modal comes up https://yourhippo.com/how-to/#newuser
however, when I use  https://yourhippo.com/how-to/#leaver I have two modals loading  one seems to be a 404  page

the code I've used is bellow  I'm not sure where exactly I've gone wrong

```
`jQuery(document).ready(function() {
console.log('modals start here');
  if (location.hash === "#leaver, #newuser") {
        jQuery('#leaver-btn-anchor-toggle,#newuser-btn-anchor-toggle').trigger('click');
  }
  
});`
```

Comment: what does `location.hash === "#leaver, #newuser"` supposed to be doing?? Are you expecting it to match either leaver or newuser? That is looking to match that exact string, not one or the other.

Comment: can't fine the dupe, but it should be `if (["#leaver", "#newuser"].includes(window.location.hash))`

Comment: the issue is  if use the following link [link]https://yourhippo.com/how-to/#leaver a modal opens over the top of the leaver modal with a page no found iframe in it for some reason

Comment: `jQuery('#leaver-btn-anchor-toggle,#newuser-btn-anchor-toggle')` says find both..... you probably want to find one.